# wxPython Create a LabelTool without adding it to a Toolbar

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, toolbar, wxwidgets

I want to create a ToolBarToolBase object without adding it visibly to the toolbar. I've tried instantiating ToolBarToolBase, but I'm using wxPython version 2.8.12.1 (I can't upgrade, I'm doing this for work) so I don't think it's fully implemented. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No. That widget is part of the toolbar. Just use a `BitmapButton` or a `PlateButton`. They both support images and would be more flexible to use anyway.

Comment: Can I put either of those on the toolbar?

Comment: Why are you creating something that you don't want shown? What is your use case? You could roll your own toolbar using `BitmapButtons` and whatnot inside of a horizontal `BoxSizer` and then use a `StaticLine` underneath.